# Two rows in the middle within a Flexbox Layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex box layout with 4 items.

```
<div class="flex-container">
   <div class="flex-items"></div>
   <div class="flex-items"></div>
   <div class="flex-items"></div>
   <div class="flex-items"></div>
</div>

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.flex-items:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  order: 0;
}

.flex-items:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  order: 0;
}

.flex-items:nth-child(3) {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  order: 0;
}

.flex-items:nth-child(4) {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  order: 0;
}
```

It currently looks like this.

[image]

I would like it so that item 2 and item 3 are one below the other.

Item 1 and Item 4 should remain as they are.

I have drawn in red what it should look like.

Unfortunately, I can't get it right at the moment.

Comment: Flex has _one_ main axis, so you are either laying out your items in rows, _or_ columns - you can't have it both ways. If you want to keep using flexbox - then you will need to wrap 2 & 3 into an additional container first; the alternative would be _Grid_.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: While flex isn't the easiest way to implement your design, it's relatively easy with CSS grid (demo: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aq8zfwpe/), if that's an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by wrapping the div in the middle with a flex container again

```css
.flex {
  display:flex 
}
.flex-row {
  flex-direction:row
}
.flex-column {
  flex-direction:column
}
.border {
  border:1px solid blue
}
.p-min {
  padding:5px
}
.flex-1{
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
 <div class='flex p-min'>
  <div class='border p-min'>item1</div>
  <div class='flex flex-column flex-1'>
    <div class='border p-min'>item 2</div>
    <div class='border p-min'>item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class='border'>item 4</div>
</div>
```